# Detect section of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I have got UICollectionView with custom layout, so there is a row of items, that are scrolling with paging. Also there is a multiple sections, so the final view is like an App Store example of final view is as below,

[image]

Problem is, to place in each section footer a page control, that will detect current page of section. I don't know how to detect in witch section scroll view offset was changed. Will appreciate any help or another solutions!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the section and row in which the collection view was selected using the following delegate method.

```
// Swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

// Obj-C
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Here, this method is invoked on the delegate only when a cell is selected. It returns indexPath.

*indexPath* contains two property you are asking for right now.

*indexPath.row*  - Gives the item currently **selected item** index in section.
*indexPath.section* - Gives the **current section** being used in the collectionView

**Note: Counting Starts from 0, not 1.**

So if I selected "*ComboCritters*" ( Look image above), I would get 0 for *indexPath.section* referring to the "New Games we love! " and, 2 for *indexPath.row* saying the 3rd item is selected.

And, that's how you get the selected section in your app.

Kind Regards,
Suman Adhikari

Comment: question was about scroll

Comment: When you tap on the screen, you still trigger the willSelectRowAtIndexPath method that would give the indexPath.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the three sections highlighted in red in your diagram as separate sections in the same collection view if you want them to independently scroll. Scrolling happens to the entire collection view, not to one section of it, unless you have a very complicated layout subclass.

It would be far simpler to have three collection views, one for each section.